# Websocket only work with ws:// but not with wss://

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, websocket

I have one site configured to work with ssl. Every request that I receive I redirect to https. Recently I implemented a websocket on it, and it work fine on development, so when I put in production I started to get this error `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://`

I created a new file locale only to connect o my websocket that is in production. When I connetc using `ws://domain` it work, when i change to `wss://domain` I got the error message.

I'm using ubuntu 18:04, Apache/2.4.18 and Rails action cable.

My Vhost is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin contato@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    LogLevel error

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ProxyPass /cable/  ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/
    ProxyPassReverse /cable/ ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin contato@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/public
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    LogLevel error

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    ProxyPass /cable/  wss://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/
    ProxyPassReverse /cable/ wss://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

On localhost out of the domain If I call `exampleSocket = new WebSocket("wss://domain.com/cable/");` I get `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://`, but if I call `exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://domain.com/cable/");` the connection work.

On site if I call `exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://domain.com/cable/");`, it dont work because of the ssl, and I get `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Anyone can help with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ...
    ProxyPass /cable/  ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/
    ...
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ...
    ProxyPass /cable/  wss://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/
```

It is unlikely that your unknown Websocket server can do both `ws://` and `wss://` on the same port 28080. It is more likely that it can do only `ws://`, i.e. you should forward to `ws://` for both port 80 and 443. Note that this is similar to what you are already correctly doing for the normal traffic: both port 80 and port 443 is forwarded to the internal `http://` and not not one to `http://` and the other to `https://`.

Comment: I changed the `ProxyPass /cable/  wss://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/` on port 443 to `ProxyPass /cable/  ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/` but it didn't work.

Comment: @AllanKlaus: Does the `https://` even work? Because *"can’t establish a connection"* might mean that nothing at port 443 works, i.e. neither `https://` nor `wss://`. And this could be caused by firewall settings which have nothing to do with the setup of Apache.

Comment: `https://` is working. When I access the domain using `http://` I'm redirect to `https://`.  On firewall both ports are enabled 

```
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp            ALLOW       Anywhere

Comment: Then please show the exact error message you get now (which might be different from the one you got before) and also check for any error messages in the apache log files.

Comment: I fixed the problem inverting the order of the ProxyPass to match first on `/cable`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Everything was going wrong because of the order of the proxypass on apache configuration file. I changed the file to this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName suaradioonline.com
    ServerAlias www.suaradioonline.com
    ServerAdmin contato@suaradioonline.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/suaradioonline.com/public
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    LogLevel error

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /cable/  ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/
    ProxyPassReverse /cable/ ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName suaradioonline.com
        ServerAlias www.suaradioonline.com
        ServerAdmin contato@suaradioonline.com.br
        DocumentRoot /var/www/suaradioonline.com/public
        ProxyRequests off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        LogLevel error

        <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /cable/  ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/
        ProxyPassReverse /cable/ ws://127.0.0.1:28080/cable/

        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

It occur beacause of the ProxyPass / match in all requests that are incoming and the request `/cable/` was never reached.